# How to use API client auto-generated by Swagger (Java - Retrofit2)?

Tags: java, swagger, retrofit2, swagger-codegen

Here is the code that Swagger generates:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/java/retrofit2

Example code is not working:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/java/retrofit2/docs/PetApi.md

`io.swagger.client.ApiException` and
`io.swagger.client.Configuration` is missing.

How to use it then? How to make requests?

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new so that the swagger codegen community can help out. We just released 2.3.0 so please check it out to see if the issue has been addressed.

Comment: I created an issue. Still the same problem in 2.3.0.